# .Net controller not receiving value in query string correctly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, query-string, getmethod

I found that if my endpoint uses method Get with [FromQuery] then the input value is parsed incorrectly. Check my image below

My postman sent request
[image]

My endpoint received the request
[image]

the GetRecruitmentsRequest definition
[image]

Query and QueryString
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the **Language** field got the value "avanced", it was supposed to receive "advanced" though

I had met this issue before, however instead of facing it, I worked around by changing the method to Post and it worked.
I guess this is a bug of .Net 6 (I am using this version) yet I haven't found any post about it

Comment: Show us your `GetRecruitmentsRequest` type definition. Are you using a custom binder?

Comment: Also, what do you see in `HttpContext.Request.Query` (and `Request.QueryString`?

Comment: hi @Dai, I have added the info you asked, does it make any sense?

Comment: My only suggestion is to fire-up Wireshark and WinDbg and attach to your web-server and see where the `d` is going missing...

Comment: Never seen this behavior before. Could you recreate it in a public git-repo?